# How to move domain HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: ssl

I've hosted my website on Amazon AWS server and everything is working fine with HTTP (http://ec2-52-77-101-230.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/) but when I'm trying to open website with HTTPS I'm getting message "refuse to connect".

Comment: Wordpress WooCommerce

Comment: Actually I've configure SSL on this domain https://laresbeauty.com/